# string passed from C++ to C# prints blank

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
#ifdef SERVER_TCP_EXPORTS
class __declspec(dllexport) Sock_Server
#else
class __declspec(dllimport) Sock_Server
#endif
{
public:
    int Server(const char* strErr,int bufSize);
    ...
 }

cpp file
int Sock_Server::Server(const char* strErr,int bufSize)
{
   // do something and assign the string to strErr
   (say) strErr = "Hello World";
   return -1;
}

in C#
[DllImport("Hello.dll", EntryPoint = "Server" CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

private extern static int Server(StringBuilder strErr, int bufSize);

public static int Connect(StringBuilder strErr, int bufSize)
{
   int res = Server(strErr,bufSize);    /// when the calls come here, strErr is empty
    return res;          // res has the value  -1
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int res = 0;
   int bufSize = 4096;
   StringBuilder strErr = new StringBuilder(bufSize+1);

   res = Connect(strErr, bufSize); //when the calls come here, strErr is empty
    MessageBox.Show(strErr.ToString());   // it has the value -1
}
```

I am not a C# guy.I did some reading before posting this out,and tried all the possible combinations but some reason it didn't work.I am using Visual Studio 2013.I have couple of Q

[Q1] When I did MessageBox.Show(strErr.ToString()); in my C#, it just prints a blank string! Would really appreciate if anyone can help me as I am pretty new to all this.

[Q2] If I give EntryPoint ="Server" my code doesn't work.It complains,enrty point of Server is not found in Hello.dll. So,every time I have to find the exact entry in my dll using dumpbin.exe and then provide exactly how the compiler has created for me

```
[DllImport("Hello.dll", EntryPoint = "?Server@Sock_Server@@QAEHPBDH@Z" CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

Is there a better way of doing this.This is making the code cupled

[Q3] Is there a way to call C++ constructor/destructor.I do need to call both of them.I have called C'tor through some other method,I know that's not a good idea.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not assign the string in C++, (you're just overwriting the provided pointer here, which any calling function won't even see). **Copy** it to the provided `strErr` buffer instead using something like `strcpy_s`.

Comment: Either you're missing a `static` somewhere or you're really trying to call an instance method as a static method, which is desperately wrong since you'd be missing `this`. And unless you overrode it on the command line, the calling convention isn't `stdcall` but "C++ specific call". And C# uses UTF-16 internally, so `char*` won't work either. And you can't instantiate C++ objects from C#, so don't worry about the destructor... there's so much wrong here I don't know where to start. My advice is to start over with a small working sample.

Comment: It is an instance function of a C++ class.  Instance functions have an extra hidden *this* parameter.  That your code doesn't crash is because you are not writing valid C++ code either, strings must be copied with strcpy_s().  You cannot pinvoke a function like this, you have no good way to create the proper value for *this*.  You must either make the function *static* or use a C++/CLI project to write a wrapper for the class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's all related to static. It's all about proper assignment of an object. The same piece of code work perfectly fine when called from other C++. I tweaked the code little bit. Now, I used strcpy_s and it's working because while marshing the data, I was loosing the data.

I am still waiting for Q2 to be answered.